# Erro quando eu tento chamar uma função

Tags: c

Eu preciso calcular a distancia entre dois pontos, mas quando eu chamo a função que faz isso (calcula a distancia), dá o erro: "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector".

Eu fiz a mesma coisa em outra função. Precisei calcular a distancia entre dois pontos e deu certo. Não sei porque agora não funciona.

Função distancia:

```
float distancia(int ax, int ay, int bx, int by)
{
    return (sqrt((pow((ax - bx), 2)) + (pow((ay - by), 2))));  
}
```

Função onde deu certo quando eu chamei 'distancia':

```
void mDistancia(char cidadeXY[][150], int coordenadasX[], int coordenadasY[], float matrizDistancia[][30])
{
    int c, i, contadorC, contadorI;
    float dij; 

    for(i = 0, contadorI = 0; i < 30; i++, contadorI += 2)
    {
        for(c = 0, contadorC = 0; c < 30; c++, contadorC += 2)
        {
            dij = distancia(coordenadasX[contadorI], coordenadasY[contadorI], coordenadasX[contadorC], coordenadasY[contadorC]);
            matrizDistancia[i][c] = dij;
        }
    }
}
```

Função onde não deu certo:

```
void problema5(char cidadeXY[][150], int coordenadasX[], int coordenadasY[])
{
    int i, j;
    float distanciaX, distanciaY;
    float dis, aux;
    int cX, cY;
    char cid[150];

    for(j = 0; j < 30; j++)
    {
        aux = distancia(coordenadasX[j], cX[j], coordenadasY[j], cY[j]);

        if(aux < dis)
        {
            dis = aux;
            strcpy(cid, cidadeXY[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Reparem que eu fiz a mesma coisa. Guardei o valor retornado na variavel float aux, assim como eu fiz com a variavel float dij. Mas só dá esse erro na função problema5.
O erro acontece duas vezes, mais especificadamente no j em coordenadasY[j] e cX[j]. Pelo menos é o que diz no terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int cX, cY;

        aux = distancia(coordenadasX[j], cX[j], coordenadasY[j], cY[j]);
        //                               ?????                   ?????
```

Nem `cX` nem `cY` sao arrays. Nao podes usar dessa maneira.

Comment: De fato, e além disso, a ordem dos parâmetros não faz o mínimo sentido no código.

Comment: Obrigada! Não tinha percebido isso no meio daquele monte de código.